Closed questions for no reason
I asked a question about transferring between iPhones, and got closed for no reason. I also wanted to know some free virtual machines that could be applicable to Macs, and after a while, it got shut down, even though both had to with Apple. If closed, comment why under this question.

I assume you are referring to Transferring to another phone, does it take up storage? and Any free VM's for Apple Silicon MacBooks?. Even though the questions are on hold, they both got answers already which may or not be helpful.
The on-hold reasons are given in the blue box on top of the questions.
For the iPhone transfer question, it states

Questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Three users asked clarification questions in the comments beneath the question. Ideally you edit the question and clarify it based on the comments. This will put the question into the review queue for reopenings.
For the VM question, the reason given is

Questions asking to recommend or find a Mac, book, tool, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Ask Different as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, edit this question to describe the problem and what research has been done so far to solve it.

I don't see an edit from your side to adress this. If you want the community to help you with clarifications, it's best raised in a comment beneath the question itself.
